SharePoint Managed Metadata column displays with additional characters in PowerApps Edit Form
I have a SharePoint Library that includes 3 Managed Metadata columns.  The user populates a SharePoint default form to create a new Doc Set, then a Canvas App populates with that data as an Approval form.  So when the user launches the PowerApp, it displays the data they entered in the Default form.  But the Managed Metadata fields populate the data + a bunch of other characters:
How can I remove those extra characters?
Thank you.

Fixed it.  All I had to do was turn off "Allow Searching" in the datacardvalue Properties.
